# How do I add a pause function to this pageChange timer?

Tags: javascript, function, iframe, timer, shuffle

Below in the code is an array of pages which is shuffled and then each of them is displayed in an iframe for a certain amount of time. I want to be able to start/stop the `pageChange` function using a button or a mouse click. Can anyone help me with this? Below is the working code, or check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xaa1qccm/ (Thanks to Nobe4)

```
var pages=[];
pages[0]="http://example.com/";
pages[1]="http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved";
pages[2]="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page";
pages[3]="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness";

 var shuffle = function(array){
     var shuffledPages = [];
     while(array.length){
         shuffledPages.push(array.splice(Math.floor(array.length*Math.random()),1));
     }
     return shuffledPages;
}


var time = 3300; 
var currentIndex = 0; 

function pageChange() { 
    if(currentIndex == 0){ 
        pages = shuffle(pages); 
        console.log(pages);
        currentIndex = pages.length; 
    }
    currentIndex--; 
    document.getElementById("frame").src=pages[currentIndex]; 
    console.log(currentIndex);
    setTimeout(function() { pageChange(); }, time);
};

pageChange();
```

Comment: when do u want to pause it?

Comment: Anytime I click the button/mouse it should stop. When clicked again it should start again.

Answer (score 0):

You may add a start/stop variable so as to check the status :

```
[...]
var time = 3300; 
var currentIndex = 0;
var stop = 0;

function pageChange() { 
    if(currentIndex == 0){ 
        pages = shuffle(pages); 
        console.log(pages);
        currentIndex = pages.length; 
    }

    if (stop == 0)
    {
        currentIndex--; 
        document.getElementById("frame").src=pages[currentIndex]; 
        console.log(currentIndex);
        setTimeout(function() { pageChange(); }, time);
    }
};

function startStop()
{
    if (stop == 0){
        stop = 1;
    }
    else{
        stop = 0;
        pageChange();
    }
}

[...]
```

And then you call `startStop()` on the click event of the button you want

**Edit :** Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xaa1qccm/2/)

Comment: Can you also call it using just left-mouseclicks?

Answer (score 0):

A variable which can be set to determine if the rotator is running, and setting that to true or false:

```
var isRunning = true;
....
<button onclick="isRunning = false">stop</button>
<button onclick="isRunning = true">start</button>
```

And check that inside your method:

```
function pageChange() { 
    if(isRunning){
       ...
    }
    setTimeout(function() { pageChange(); }, time);
};
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/xaa1qccm/1/

Comment: This is working perfectly for me, thank you! Could you show me how to make just 1 button of the 2 buttons? So the 'stop' button changing into the 'start' button and back again?